# Polymer paper-dropdown-menu issues -- menu overlay not working

Tags: polymer

Very frustrating, not sure what's going on. I can't find exactly what I need to import to get the paper-dropdown-menu menu to pop up like in the demo -- I've imported the same components that are in the demo, plus some, but to no avail. I've taken it in an entirely separate file and it's not working still. Any ideas?

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="versions">
    <paper-dropdown layered class="dropdown">
        <core-menu class="menu">
            <paper-item>version 1</paper-item>
            <paper-item>version 2</paper-item>
        </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Can anyone tell me or point me to the page which states exactly which components I need to import? I can't seem to find it anywhere.. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**edit** just ran the demo file on my appengine test server and it's not showing the overlayed menu either.. hmmmmm

**edit** my import statements:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'.
</script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-elements/core-elements.html">
```

**edit** I've tried re-downloading the 5.1 paper-dropdown-menu folder directly from Git, no dice. The `demo.html`included also doesn't run when I ran it on my test server

**edit** After importing the `paper-dropdown-menu.html` file separately from the `paper-elements.html` file the top-tier paper-dropdown appears to be working. I guess that the paper-dropdown-menu isn't included in the latest version of `paper-elements.html`? I'm back to my original issue of my overlay still not working, however. I'm not sure what element I need to import in order to get this to work. I was under the impression that it used the `paper-dropdown-transition` but I'm not sure, I can't seem to find it in the documentation anywhere. Halp!

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my issue! I needed to have both of these imported in order to get it to appear!

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/web-animations-next/web-animations.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/web-animations-js/web-animations.html">
```

I only had the web-animations-next imported previously. I wish I knew where this stuff was documented if anyone wants to post a link still!

Comment: This didn't work for me, in fact my bower_components did not include the folder web-animations-next and files contained therein.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure paper item, not sure though. Give it a try.

Or, better yet, just import paper elements and get everything.

Comment: Hmm interesting, well after importing paper-elements my paper-items now are showing up, but the menu is not showing up, or functioning. hmmmm..

Comment: @shanling import core elements as well.

Comment: The only thing that is working is the paper-items now, not the menu title or the arrow icon. hmmmm, no errors in my console on chrome.. interesting

Comment: @shanling could you please post your import statements?

Comment: I would make a JSbin to post but JSbin only has polymer 3.1 :-( i believe paper-dropdown-menu was added in the latest 5.1 version

Comment: @shanling Found the problem! You put "webcomponentjs/webcomponentjs.js" when you need "webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js". In other words, you forgot the S and need to take off js on the JS file but keep .js (so it's just webcomponents.js) :)

Comment: whoops that was actually a typo on me pasting it to stackoverflow >_> sorry! good catch though! Still not working.. hmmm.. is there a css class I need to add to paper-dropdown-menu perhaps? It has its height and width at 0x0, and even if I change it manually in the css it won't budge.. interesting

Comment: @shanling also, your first script starts with a " but ends with a '.  Also there's a Random period at the end.  I don't know if this is in your actual code or not though.

Comment: yeah it's fine in my code, i had to write the script to load it in on stackoverflow because I have a different script that loads it in on my index.html file that does some wonky internet explorer excluding shenanigans, but I've checked and that isn't the issue. It's definitely loading the webcomponents.js because all my elements are showing up -- just the dropdown that's messy. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Try removing that layered attribute maybe? I'm scratching my head haha.

Comment: Also bower update and make sure core-elements is installed and your bower.json file has the right dependencies (0.5.1).

Comment: yeah -- nada! It's very strange as I copied it exactly from the demo and it refuses to work.. Even the demo refuses to work! And yeah I updated it through bower with the latest stuff and no dice :-( I'll have to make my own dropdown I guess with js. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @shanling I'll try it on my own and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Good news! I got it to work.  I'll put it on github tomorrow (it's 1:00am here) so you can download the entire thing (including the bower components folder because I think yours got corrupt).  Just erase your entire folder (including your bower json file) and download the one I upload.  I'll tell you once I upload it but I better go to bed lol

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :-) I'll await your upload! I'll try downloading it directly from git also.. see if that helps. Thanks!